# upload a file manually and progress bar with rest time, Plupload

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, progress-bar, plupload

I am very new in php and javascript.I need help by two code changing. I have a file uploading code with chunk option from Plupload. This code upload my file immediately after I choose the file. I need to change the code to upload my file manually with Send button. Next code changing, I need a progress bar to show me the rest time of uploading. This code gave me just a precent number of uploading. Thank you in advance for your help

Here is my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chunking Upload Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="x-dummy.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) UPLOAD BUTTON & FILE LIST -->
    <form>
      <div id="list"></div>
      <input type="button" id="pick" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <!-- (B) LOAD PLUPLOAD FROM CDN -->
    <!-- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/plupload -->
    <!-- https://www.plupload.com/ -->
    <script src="js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // (C) INITIALIZE UPLOADER
    window.onload = () => {
      // (C1) GET HTML FILE LIST
      var list = document.getElementById("list");

      // (C2) INIT PLUPLOAD
      var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: "html5",
        browse_button: "pick",
        url: "2b-chunk.php",
        chunk_size: "10mb",
        init: {
          PostInit: () => list.innerHTML = "<div>Ready</div>",
          FilesAdded: (up, files) => {
            plupload.each(files, file => {
              let row = document.createElement("div");
              row.id = file.id;
              row.innerHTML = `${file.name} (${plupload.formatSize(file.size)}) <strong></strong>`;
              list.appendChild(row);
            });
            uploader.start();
          },
          UploadProgress: (up, file) => {
            document.querySelector(`#${file.id} strong`).innerHTML = `${file.percent}%`;
          },
          Error: (up, err) => console.error(err)
        }
      });
      uploader.init();
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my upload php code called 2b-chunk.php

```
<?php
// (A) HELPER FUNCTION - SERVER RESPONSE
function verbose ($ok=1, $info="") {
  if ($ok==0) { http_response_code(400); }
  exit(json_encode(["ok"=>$ok, "info"=>$info]));
}

// (B) INVALID UPLOAD
if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES["file"]["error"]) {
  verbose(0, "Failed to move uploaded file.");
}

// (C) UPLOAD DESTINATION - CHANGE FOLDER IF REQUIRED!
$filePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads";
if (!file_exists($filePath)) { if (!mkdir($filePath, 0777, true)) {
  verbose(0, "Failed to create $filePath");
}}
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filePath = $filePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// (D) DEAL WITH CHUNKS
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
if ($out) {
  $in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb");
  if ($in) { while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) { fwrite($out, $buff); } }
  else { verbose(0, "Failed to open input stream"); }
  @fclose($in);
  @fclose($out);
  @unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
} else { verbose(0, "Failed to open output stream"); }

// (E) CHECK IF FILE HAS BEEN UPLOADED
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) { rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath); }
verbose(1, "Upload OK");
?>
```

I tried to find a resolution in internet without any success. I will be happy if someone can give me some help.

Comment: Remove `uploader.start();` from the `FilesAdded` method. Did you even read the code?